# Set a Plug Configuration Value via BootStrap or _Event script

Tags: grails

I have a few servers and I don't want to hard-code the hostnames into the Config.groovy file for plugins that need them.

Can I dynamically set plugin config values via BootStrap where I can use LinkGenerator?

Comment: Mainly because I have too many servers and too many applications to make this a sane process. If I had a nickel for every time something wasn't configured right at the server level I wouldn't be asking this question and instead be on a private island somewhere. I like to self-contain the needs of the application as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override config basically at any moment in grails.  So doing it in `Bootstrap.groovy` is possible.  Yet not every plugin have to read the config each time it needs it, so you might be to late at that point and the plugin already holds the old config var and never checks again.

It's usually better to integrate a change for the actual envrionment into the regular config.  So you can roll out your `prod` war, but fetch config from the actual server/vm.  The standard `Config.groovy` already contains example code to read several config files or you can read the value from a system envrionment variable.  After all `Config.groovy` behaves like a regular groovy script.  You can also read a system file from `/etc` or execute a command.

From a default 2.4.4 project:

```
// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
// config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
// in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
                            "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
                            "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
   grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
}
```

You can also just set from environment directly:

```
grails.serverURL = System.properties["MYAPP_SERVER_URL"]
```

Or get it via `hostname`:

```
grails.serverURL = "http://${'hostname'.execute().text.trim()}"
```

Comment: I just figured out configuration happens before BootStrap, so my thought is not an option.

Comment: in that case please provide a concrete example, what you are after. or if you have tried already with bootstrap and something is not working provide what you have tried.

Comment: I did breakpoints in Debugger and determined BootStrap init is executed after config consumption.

Comment: I took your advice. I'll probably have setup our CI to set a JAVA_OPTS param.